# Abrir aplicación desde el navegador

Tags: google-chrome

Hola he hecho una aplicación y quiero que se pueda abrir desde el navegador con una url de la forma que hace chrome  por ejemplo "chrome://history/" que yo al introducir "myApp://history/" abra mi aplicación se que hay aplicaciones que lo hacen pero no se como

Comment: te refieres a un archivo interno? O que la aplicación se ejecute en el navegador?

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez que al meter ese comando abra mi aplicación directamente con el parámetro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es registrar un protocolo de URL personalizado. Tienes más información en la [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) (windows)

Comment: Gracias ya he visto que el problema es que añadía un "/" si era una ruta de archivo!

Comment: @jooooooooota Si mi respuesta te ha solucionado el problema puedes marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo.